# Google Drive Api not working on server

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to upload files on google drive. First I created a folder on google drive, then uploaded files in that folder. It's working on localhost properly.

But when we publish this project on a server, it is not working.

Comment: Please can you post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the way the question is written at the moment, we are going to have a very hard time to guess what the issue could be

Comment: Please Can you Elaborate what you have done and where you have struck and what the problem its occurring.

Comment: I really want to help, but I do not understand where the problem is happening, please add more details
Generally, the files need to be stored on the server just as they are on your local machine and this should work. But again you will add a clear explanation and I will gladly answer you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to invalid authentication. Is your server is located in the same region? Google gives the authentication error if region change.

This can the resaon. that why you are able to upload files fro locally not from Server.